# How to highlight the button in backgroundview when popupview appeared?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any code for highlighting the button in backgroungview? If I Press the button it should be highlighted and also popupview should appear in the same screen.Like this image

[image]

Comment: How you are displaying popupview?

Comment: popupObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popup"];
popupObj.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 168);
[self.view addSubview:popupObj.view];
[self addChildViewController:popupObj];

Comment: i dont think so you can ...better take a copy of button with same position into popup view also.before showing popup hide background button.

Comment: Will it work for all the scenario?

Comment: https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView Try this library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While clicking ,  you just add the another button to UIWindow.... So u get the popup like appearance of button..